# Список list, метод sort

Tags: c++

Имею `list` узлов с указателями на предыдущие элементы (дерево,если его так можно назвать). Существуют так же элементы, но указывают на `NULL`.

Суть проблемы в том, что при использовании метода `sort` на `list` мне необходимо, чтобы узел с указателями на `NULL` был перемещён в конец `list` (при этом поле по которому происходит сравнение у узла с указателями на `NULL` и указателями на другие элементы одинаково); соответственно, `sort` не срабатывает и оставляет узел с указателями на `NULL` в середине списка.

Для сортировки использую следующую перегрузку:

```
struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Hafm* l, const Hafm* r) const {
    if(l->left!=NULL && l->right!=NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return (l->a < r->a);
    }
};
```

Сам цикл с созданием дерева:

```
while (t.size()!=1)
{  
    t.sort(MyCompare());//сортируем лист первых элементов 
    Hafm *SonL = t.front();//Вешаем на вспомогательные сыновей
    t.pop_front();//удаляем первого сына
    Hafm *SonR = t.front();
    t.pop_front();//так же чистим     
    Hafm *parent = new Hafm(SonL,SonR); 
    t.push_back(parent);
}
```

Конструктор Hafm:

```
Hafm(Hafm *L, Hafm *R)//Конструктор с параметрами 
{  
    left =  L;//Левый сын
    right = R;//Правый сын
    a = L->a + R->a;//Сумма информ.полей сыновей  
}
```

В перегрузке после захода в `if` выкидывает ошибку:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...s\ALEX MERCER\Desktop\Lab_2_TIK\LAB_2_TIK\Debug\LAB_2_TIK.exe
>   File: d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list
>   Line: 1324
>
> Expression: invalid operator<
>
> For information on how you program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

Comment: Вообще-то для начала - какой же это list?...

Answer (score 3):

Думаю проблема в том, что ваш предикат не обеспечивает [строгое слабое упорядочение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Чтобы обеспечить строгое слабое упорядочение ваш предикат должен обладать следующими свойствами:

- **Антирефлексивность**: `x < x` всегда `false`.
- **Ассиметричность**: Если `x < y`, тогда `y < x` всегда `false`.
- **Транзитивность**: Если `x < y` и `y < z`, тогда `x < z` всегда `true`.
- **Транзитивность несопоставимости**: Если `x` и `y` несопоставимы, и `y` и `z` несопоставимы, тогда `x` и `z` тоже несопоставимы.